# How to tell google bot that page not found in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, server-side-rendering

I have a React App with Routers, I also have 404 component, etc.
But I don't know how to send 404 header to google bot.

I'mm just thinking that it's not possible due React app without SSR.
Am I right?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `Router`, you can set your pages like this:

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path = "/home" component={HomePage} />
        <Route exact path = "/sign-up" component={SignUpPage} />
        <Route exact path = "/login" component={LoginPage} />
        <Route exact path="/incorrect-login" component={IncorrectLoginPage} />
        <Route exact path = "*" component={PageNotFound} /> //404 Component
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

With this, you set your `PageNotFound` to the bottom of your router list where if the url of the React App does not correspond to any of your previous urls, then the `PageNotFound` route is triggered. You can just render your not found component under that page like you would for any other page in your application.

I also used `exact` so that the url must be exactly the same along with a `Switch` statement so that only a SINGLE page component can be triggered at once. The `*` basically just means ALL other urls besides those specified previously.

The `PageNotFound` is treated as kind of like a default catch statement so it's at the bottom

Comment: But what about googlebot interpretation of it?